# Rsyslogd config error

Tags: configuration, rsyslog

I have this rsyslog.conf file:

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*             /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*            -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*              -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*               -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
user.*              -/var/log/user.log
local1.*            -/var/log/local1.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info           -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn           -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err            /var/log/mail.err

#
# Logging for INN news system.
#
news.crit           /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err            /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice         -/var/log/news/news.notice

#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none      -/var/log/messages

#
# Emergencies are sent to everybody logged in.
#
*.emerg             :omusrmsg:*

#
# I like to have messages displayed on the console, but only on a virtual
# console I usually leave idle.
#
#daemon,mail.*;\
#   news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
#   *.=debug;*.=info;\
#   *.=notice;*.=warn   /dev/tty8

# The named pipe /dev/xconsole is for the `xconsole' utility.  To use it,
# you must invoke `xconsole' with the `-file' option:
# 
#    $ xconsole -file /dev/xconsole [...]
#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   |/dev/xconsole
```

But when I run the command `rsyslogd -N1`, I have the following error:

```
rsyslogd: version 5.8.11, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: WARNING: rsyslogd is running in compatibility mode. Automatically generated config directives may interfer with your rsyslog.conf settings. We suggest upgrading your config and adding -c5 as the first rsyslogd option.
rsyslogd: CONFIG ERROR: could not interpret master config file '/etc/rsyslog.conf'. [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
rsyslogd: EMERGENCY CONFIGURATION ACTIVATED - fix rsyslog config file!
rsyslogd: Warning: backward compatibility layer added to following directive to rsyslog.conf: ModLoad immark
rsyslogd: Warning: backward compatibility layer added to following directive to rsyslog.conf: MarkMessagePeriod 1200
rsyslogd: Warning: backward compatibility layer added to following directive to rsyslog.conf: ModLoad imuxsock
```

I actually uncommented the following lines

```
# provides UDP syslog reception

    $ModLoad imudp
    $UDPServerRun 514
```

and added the following line

```
local1.*            -/var/log/local1.log
```

but I do not believe this is the consequence of my error.

Any idea why I get this error?

***UPDATE [15 dec 2013 @14:41]***

As suggested by [[Nikolaidis Fotis]](https://serverfault.com/users/48246/nikolaidis-fotis), I stopped the service (service rsyslog stop) and started manually:

```
root@xxxx:/# /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5 -v

rsyslogd 5.8.11, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    FEATURE_LARGEFILE:          No
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run rsyslog in debug mode and with non-compatibility mode ( -c5 for example)

Comment: It responds that it is "Already running...".  Can I add this option in a starting bash file ? For now, I executed your suggestion as root on a command line.

Comment: You must kill the previous instance (/etc/init.d/rsyslogd stop) 
Can you try it again ? what's the output ?

Comment: Nik, see update in question

Comment: And if you use -d flag what does it print ?

Comment: Hum, the error was the rsyslog.conf file (actually linked (ln -s)) wrongly linked to a mispelled filename.  The -d option helped me view a more detailed report of the error.